# Compare date in serialized string MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, date, serialization

It is not my code, its something that I need to get it done without modifying the structure of table. I know it would be very easy to just store date as MySQL date format but I cant do that.

There is a column in table which stores serialized array as a string. Now I need to select all rows whose 'date' is less than today.

This date is inside serialized array string.

Is there a way to compare it on mysql query? An example string is:

```
a:3:{s:4:"test";b:1;s:2:"se";i:1;s:4:"date";s:10:"2013-05-23";}
```

I need to compare the "date" from this string to mysql date using the following query:

```
"date" BETWEEN 2013-01-01 AND 2013-05-23
```

Comment: Why you store data like this?

Comment: I dont, its stored like that I just need to write a query for it. And i can not do anything to restructure it

Comment: @Kamil it looks like the OP has no control over how the data is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the date value (assuming it's always set off by `"date";s:10`) using nested [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) calls. The inner one returns everything after `"date";s:10"` and the outer one cuts off the closing quote and whatever follows:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '"date";s:10:"', -1), '"', 1)
```

If `val` is `a:3:{s:4:"test";b:1;s:2:"se";i:1;s:4:"date";s:10:"2013-05-23";}` as in your example, this will return `2013-05-23`. Then your query can be:

```
...
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '"date";s:10:"', -1), '"', 1) BETWEEN 2013-01-01 AND 2013-05-23
```

Not pretty, but we can't expect pretty here :)

Comment: what if there are other values that have length 10 then it will break right ?

Comment: Oh, I see - I thought `s:10` meant "here comes a date" when it really means `string 10`, doesn't it? In that case, the answer to "will it break" is basically "yes" because it will return the last `s:10` value. If you have two `string 10` values, what do you do to tell them apart?

Comment: maybe have "date" as part since "date" is the key of array its like ['date'] = '2013-05-23' translated in string is `s:4:"date";s:10:"2013-5-23"`

Comment: Ah, I get it now. You'd just need to add the `"date";` in the expression. I'll update my answer. Sorry, I got lost in that sea of colons and quotes :)

Comment: thanks alot, i think its working. Gotta do lots of testing now.

Comment: Getting that dates inside queries will obfuscate your code a lot. Maybe create some database view, or SQL function to "normalize" these dates?

Comment: Good call @Kamil. GGio, if you'll be querying this table a lot please consider Kamil's suggestion. Like I said, the query isn't pretty :)

Comment: One more thing - ff you have many records with serialized data like this (by many i mean 10000 or more) - date stored like this will ruin your performance, because of no index on date field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get date with substring with starting character -13 (13 from right side) and length of 10.

Something like this:

```
SUBSTR(field_name, -13, 10)
```

Comment: but its not always the last element of array. can it be done using regex?

Comment: I think regex is not bad idea, but im not enough familiar with regex to help you. I think Ed Gibbs solution is pretty good. Just pack it into a function or view.

Answer (score 0):

select * from  postmeta where  meta_key = 'your_meta_key' and meta_value REGEXP  ('6')